# Help with getParent() downcast

Tags: android

I'm learning android/java and have this example code I can't get to work:

```
OnRatingBarChangeListener l = new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
 public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
   boolean fromTouch) {
  Integer myPos=(Integer)ratingBar.getTag();
  RowModel model=getModel(myPos);
  model.rating = rating;

  LinearLayout p=(LinearLayout)ratingBar.getParent();
  TextView l=(TextView)p.findViewById(R.id.label);
  l.setText(model.toString());
 }
};
```

Everything works except the LinearLayout / getParent() downcast. At runtime it creates a ClassCastException. If I comment out that block of code then everthing works fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, `ratingBar.getParent()` doesn't return a LinearLayout. Find out what static type ratingBar.getParent() returns, and use (a reference of ) that type to assign to.

Perhaps you think that `ratingBar` is-a LinearLayout, and you're confused about Java precedence? Method call operator `.` has higher precedence than the cast operator `(type)`. It's unlikely, but maybe you meant to do this:

```
LinearLayout p=( (LinearLayout)ratingBar ).getParent();
```

Comment: I have added the following to see what is returned:

    selection.setText(ratingBar.getParent().toString());

and the output is as follows:

    android.widget.LinearLayout@4377c0a8